# Excel: Chart that rounds...dates?

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2010

Why excel decided to round DATES?!how to turn off this weird rounding? [image].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the x-axis, select Format Axis, and either:

- change Base Unit to **Days**, or
- change Axis Type to **Text**